# Kendo UI Server Side Paging/Filtering/Sorting Wrapper on Command

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, kendo-ui

Is there a server side Kendo UI Grid wrapper for sorting/paging/filtering on an sqlCommand. I am currently using the MVC wrapper for a dataset. Because the dataset is to large it takes a while to create everthing though. Im using something like so:

```
Function Index(request AS DataSourceRequest) As ActionResult
    return Json(GetOrgs().ToDataSourceResults(request))
End Function

Function GetOrgs() AS List(Of Organization)
    Using con as ...
        Dim com as command("select...",con)
        read into object list
    End Using
End Function
```

The GetOrgs() is retrieving the organizations as a List(Of Organization) and all the filtering/sorting/paging is done with ToDataSourceResults.
Creating the list/objects takes too long on a large dataset so my question is then if there is some wrapper to add the paging/filtering/sorting to the orgs so i can do something more like.

```
Function Index(request AS DataSourceRequest) As ActionResult
   return Json(GetOrgs(request))
End Function

Function GetOrgs(request AS DataSourceRequest) AS List(Of Organization)
    Using con as ...
        Dim com as command(SourceRequest??("select...", request),con)
        read into object list
    End Using
 End Function
```

This way we only pull the fields we need from the database instead of a large dataset.